# Angular 9: Browser Initiator when API is called

Tags: angular, browser, angular9, polyfills

I have migrated my Project from AngularJS to Angular 9.1 and Framework 4.7 to Core 3.1. The major issue we are facing after migrating is in API calls. This is randomly taking longer time getting the response from the service.

We are using latest chrome & firefox browsers for testing.

One thing I noticed is when we run our Angular APP using with ng build and check the network tab in chrome developer tool the API calls Initiator is zone-evergreen.js as shown below
[image: ANGULAR CLI]

But when I use the same using Non CLI page MVC index page i.e. index.cshtml & build the angular project using ng build --prod the API call Initiator is pollyfills.js as shown below
[image: Non CLI Angular]

I have added the below in index.cshtml

```js
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<!-- zone.js required by Angular -->
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="~/runtime.js" defer></script>
<script src="~/polyfills.js" defer></script>
<script src="~/scripts.js" defer></script>
<script src="~/main.js" defer></script>
```

Can anyone update is this the normal behavior of API initiator loading from pollyfills?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Nilesh have you found any solution even me too facing same issue. If you found any solution please update the answer